# Store binnin models in R after fitting a dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm looking for algorithms to create bins of variables in order to reduce the noise.
I have found several libraries for that, one if the chi2 library:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/discretization/versions/1.0-1/topics/chi2

The documentation has the following example:

```
data(iris)
#---cut-points
chi2(iris,0.5,0.05)$cutp

#--discretized dataset using Chi2 algorithm
chi2(iris,0.5,0.05)$Disc.data
```

This works for this data, but if I train a model after transforming this data in order to make predicction over new records I will have to use the same cuts that were used here. My question is, is there any method or library that stored the cuts of the bins in a way that can be easiy applied to new data similarly to a predict method? whitout any custom function

Comment: Please include all relevant code that is necessary to reproduce this in your example, [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)